# Does the web application project deployment package has web.config file un encrypted

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

Does the web application project deployment package has web.config file un encrypted. 
What is the use of Package. why they say that in web application project only 1 dll is deployed however web.config file is still residing with connection string un encrypted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was not clear from the beginning. Dave answered correctly. The web.config is indeed **unencrypted by default, regardless of the project type you use**. You could encrypt it using the instructions given in [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) or [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which explains how to encrypt and decrypt configuration sections.

Answering to "what is the difference between a web application project over a website project", [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes thoroughly the differences between the two project types, including a summary.

I would suggest using a web application project. The most important benefits (in my opinion) when using a web application project are:

- Building produces a dll. This means that when you publish your application, there is no source code on the server. Be careful: **This does not mean that your published code is encrypted.** Anybody who has access on the server could see your code using a disassembler (like [MSIL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). If you want to make reverse engineering harder, you could use an obfurscator like [confuser](http://confuser.codeplex.com/).
- You make debugging easier as the project file contains references to other projects etc. You can also [edit and continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) while debugging.
- You have more visual studio options available, regarding build/publish process. You could for example add prebuild/postbuild steps, using [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) or [Team Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668945.aspx).

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

web.config file is unencrypted by default, but you can encrypt sections of it if needed.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx for more info.

Comment: I know we can encrypt it. My question was that: Has the Package in web-application-project (WAP) contains web.config and will it be hiding the information of connection string. If not then what is the benefit of WAP over Website project?

Comment: If you amend your question to ask that, I will post an answer to it. There are many reasons to use a web application project and many reasons why you should avoid a website project.